# Validation messages only working for all not specific model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to display an error message for a specific field not all possible error messages on the model.  When I use the below code it works, however it will list them all.

`<div class="validation text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>`

The below code does not work for trying to display a message for a specific model property:

`<span asp-validation-for="MajorSelection" class="validation text-error"></span>`

Below is how I am adding the error message onto the model state in the controller:

`ModelState.AddModelError(majorChangeVM.MajorSelection, "Invalid Major Selection");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code should look like this

```
ModelState.AddModelError("MajorSelection", "Invalid Major Selection");
```